# Got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SAXSVGDocumentFactory when using Interleaved2Of5 Barcode format

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror, batik

I am trying to print a list of barcodes, data for which which will be sent to the JasperReports *jrxml* in a List of Strings.

I am successful in printing the barcodes using barbeque format, but now I have to change the format of barcode to **barcode4j Interleaved2Of5.** I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

But still getting the below error while running the code:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SAXSVGDocumentFactory`

Can any one tell me if there is any issue with the dependecies added or I need to add any other dependecies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.7*** artifact to fix this issue.

As you can see the class is here:

[image: The content of package]

***Notes***

BTW, you can use [findjar.com](https://www.findjar.com) to find jar or class you need. 
You can check this [url](https://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SAXSVGDocumentFactory.html) to get information where you can find ***org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory*** class.

[image]